# Would GCC linker check the compatible of declarations and definition?

Tags: c, gcc

I have a question about the compatible checking behavior of gcc linker, looks like it won’t check the compatible of declarations and definition.

For example, I defined a `uint32_t` variable `eTest` in file **a.c**, and then declare it with `uint8_t` type in file **b.c** as below, it’s supposed that there is a warning since the type of `eTest` be changed in the declarations. However, there is no any warning message be popped. 
And looks like the statement of the variable type in the declarations is unnecessary, because these is also no warning although declare the variable without type statement.

**a.c**

```
uint32_t eTest = 0;
```

**b.c**

```
extern uint8_t eTest;
```

Comment: You miss some of the fundamental concepts of C. What does you C book say? What **specifically is unclear?

Answer (score 0):

> For example, I defined a uint32_t variable eTest in file a.c, and then declare it with uint8_t type in file b.c as below, it’s supposed that there is a warning since the type of eTest be changed in the declarations.

This is **implementation specific**. BTW, on Linux with a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler used with ***link time optimizations*** (so practically compile all your `.c` files and *link* the object files with `gcc -flto -O2`, e.g. with `make CC='gcc -flto -O2'`) you *will get* a diagnostic.

However, `-flto` slows down the compilation time (by nearly doubling it).

Ad Kerrek SB told in [his deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44325750/841108) this violation is not required to be detected, and concretely your program have some [**undefined behavior**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). For C11, check [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (I glanced briefly and did not found any explicit requirement to detect your situation).

Practically speaking the `extern uint8_t eTest;` declaration should sit in some common header file `myheader.h` which you should `#include` in all your source files (notably `a.c`), and then you will get an error (even without `-flto`). So even if you correct the type, coding as you did is very poor taste. You need to centralize shared declarations in some common header file. Read more about the [C preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor). So both `a.c` and `b.c` should contain (near their start) `#include "myheader.h"` and that `myheader.h` header file should have `extern uint8_t eTest;`.

Notice that with `-flto` the (`lto1` & `cc1` inside GCC) compiler is used both at "compile" time and at "link" time. The real [*binutils*](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/) `ld` or `gold` linker (which would be run by `gcc`) does not know about types. An [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) symbol has (nearly) no type (actually data & functions are still separated).

Comment: (I gave an answer for C++, not for C. I don't know the relevant rules for C, though I imagine they're similar.)